# Multi-table SQL search query

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing an app that interacts with a MySQL database.

I have 3 tables, 'categories', 'books' and 'book_category'.

```
/* stores properties for categories */
`categories` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `name` varchar(140) NOT NULL UNIQUE,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);


/* stores properties for books */
`books` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `title` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` tinyint(1) NOT NULL default 0, 
  `creation_date` timestamp NOT NULL default CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);

/* matches books against categories */
`book_category` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
);
```

I have 2 variables to perform the search.

```
<?php
    $categoryString = 'python';  // books saved under python
    $readBool = 1;  // all books that have been read
?>
```

I would like to write the following SQL query:

**Select all python books that have been read(i.e, book.read = 1).**

My SQL knowledge is very limited, please help.

Comment: in book_category table item_id is foreign for book table id?

Comment: looks like book_category.category_ID = categories.id and book_category.item_id=books.id  so a simple join or 2 should do it :)

Comment: @D Mac, no its a side project that I'm working on. Moving from MongoDB to MySQL https://github.com/qawemlilo/nodebookmarks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
SELECT books.id, books.title, books.`read`, categories.name
FROM books
INNER JOIN book_category ON books.id = book_category.item_id
INNER JOIN categories ON book_category.category_id = categories.id
WHERE books.read = 1
AND categories.name = 'python'
```

And here's an [SQL fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/05434/7) to demonstrate.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this-

```
select * from book_category
   LEFT JOIN books ON book_category.item_id = books.id
   LEFT JOIN category ON category.id = book_category.category_id
  WHERE category.name = 'python' AND
        book.read = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select b.title 
from books b
left join book_category bc on (b.id=bc.item_d) 
left join categories c on (c.id=bc.category_id) 
where b.read=1 and c.name='python'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM books WHERE id IN (
    SELECT item_id FROM book_category WHERE category_id IN (
        SELECT id FROM category WHERE name = 'Python'
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM books AS b
  INNER JOIN book_category AS bc
    ON bc.item_id = b.id
  INNER JOIN categories AS c
    ON c.id = bc.category_id
WHERE b.read = 1 AND c.name='python'
```

Comment: include `c.name='python'` in where

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT b.title 
FROM books b, categories c, book_category bc
WHERE b.id = bc.item_id
  AND c.id = bc.category_id
  AND b.read
  AND c.name = 'python'
```

To make sure that your query works fast, make sure that you have following indexes:

```
 books(id)
 categories(id, name)
 book_category(item_id)
 book_category(caregory_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
"select b.title from category c INNER JOIN book_category bc on bc.category_id = c.id INNER JOIN book b on b.id = b.id where b.read = '1' and c.name = 'python'";
```